# Automatically open file with custom boilerplate code according to file extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, boilerplate

For example, if I open a .tex file, I would like it to automatically contain some code like `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` that I defined. And if I open a .c file, it should already have`#include<stdio.h> ... int main(){return 0;}` and so on. (I would like to define the boilerplate code.)

Is there a functionality in VS Code that will enable me to do this?

Comment: You can define single character key snippets for each language type, like '!' for html in emmet, or some other small word 'start', 'go'

Comment: @rioV8, where exactly?

Comment: `File > Preferences > User Snippets`